# Background image won't show via URL (HTML & CSS)

Tags: html, css, image, url, background

So I had been watching tutorials on how to code with html, and I succeeded at first with the whole background-image: url('somePicture.jpg');
but my issue now is that it doesn't show up at all. I've been learning all week last week but over the weekend I took a break and now I come back to my office and I ruined everything.
Here's what I have now:

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Syne', serif;
}
#help{
    color: purple;
}
.what{
    font-weight: bold;
}
section{
    border: solid 5px purple;
    padding: 20px 5px 10px 5px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
}
main{
    background-image: rgb(59, 59, 187) url("https://photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/img013-1200-copy.jpg") center/contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Syne&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Christ.css">
<title>
    Wow
</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <section>
                <h1 id="help">Oh.</h1>
                <p class="what">Hello, I exist. This is text. Welcome.</p>
            </section>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using `background-image` (which is *just* for the image url) instead of `background`  (which allows shorthand for other properties such as center etc.

Comment: Thanks so much, your explanation really helped me remember the difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the property you've gotten confused between the `background` property and `background-image` property. I just changed the CSS code to use `background` instead of `background-image` and it works expectedly.